# Webkit browsers transform: translate incorrect behaviour

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a sliding search box.

When you press the button search box should slide out from the button.

I'm trying to make it with translateX(100%) property.

But on WebKit based browsers initial translateX(100%) doesn't work.

And when I'm switching translateX from 100% to 0 it slides in the wrong direction.
Firefox + Edge - everything is ok.

Webkit issue only.

I'm sure I missed something, or maybe this is a well-known bug?

How can I fix this behaviour?

Thank you!

Jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/timonbandit/dm9u0w7t/44/

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="/search" class="m-search-box__form">
<div class="m-search-box__input-wrp">
<input autofocus="autofocus" class="m-search-box__input" type="search">
</div>
<button class="m-search-box__submit" type="submit">I</button>
</form>
```

```css
.m-search-box__form {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  width: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.m-search-box__input-wrp {
  position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 35px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.m-search-box__input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.m-search-box__input.opened {
  transform: translateX(0)
}

.m-search-box__submit {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```js
$(".m-search-box__submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $(".m-search-box__submit").toggleClass("opened");
  $(".m-search-box__input").toggleClass("opened");

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution.

```
<form action="/search" class="m-search-box__form">

<div class="m-search-box__input-wrp">

  <input class="m-search-box__input" type="search">

</div>

<button class="m-search-box__submit" type="submit">

  I

</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/timonbandit/dm9u0w7t/46/

And found a related topic.

The problem is in autofocus attribute in WebKit-based browsers.

If an element contains autofocus attribute - WebKit will show it anyway :-)

So the solution there is removing autofocus attribute or take the answer from this topic - [Why is transition started up with autofocus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376605/why-is-transition-started-up-with-autofocus)